# "No, of course not" vs "Of course not"

Tags: meaning, difference, negative-concord

What is more correct, **No, of course not** or **Of course not**? 
For example if I am asked:

> Would you mind looking after my bag?

I can answer

> Of course not.

But if I answer

> No, of course not.

Is it correct too? 
I do understand that they have the same sense. In my view **No, of course not** is slightly overloaded.

Comment: Note you could also answer in the affirmative and it would mean the same thing, even if it's not technically correct. E.g. "Would you mind looking after my bag?" "Sure!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the original poster's examples are correct and natural in Standard English.  Which one is used depends on whether the person responding first thought to say "No", or first thought to say "Of course".